# Javascript/Jquery fix for chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The attached code redirects to Google when back button is pressed. The code works on desktop and on Firefox Mobile but it doesn't work on Chrome mobile.

We want the code to work on mobile Chrome either by modifying the existing code attached or by using a new one.
https://pastebin.com/ajh6SJUJ

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

              $(window).on('popstate', function() {
                var hashLocation = location.hash;
                var hashSplit = hashLocation.split("#!/");
                var hashName = hashSplit[1];

                if (hashName !== '') {
                var hash = window.location.hash;
                    if (hash === '') {
                        //alert('Back button was pressed.');
                        window.location='https://google.com';
                        return false;
                    }
                }
              });

              window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');

            }

        });
</script>
```

Comment: You might try using window.location.href instead of just window.location.

Comment: When running this code i get on console: "SecurityError: The operation is insecure". FF v68